# Are the following definitions of projective space equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

In several algebraic geometry texts, I have seen projective space $\mathbb P^n$ (over a field $k$) be defined in two ways for $n\ge0$:

1. The set of one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb A^{n+1}$.
2. The quotient set $\left(\mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\right)/\sim$, where two points $p,q\in A^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ are considered to be equivalent if one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Although many authors assert that these definitions of $\mathbb P^n$ are equivalent, it seems to me that technically they are not. The elements in $\mathbb P^{n}$ in (1) contain the origin $0$, whereas the elements in $\mathbb P^{n}$ in (2) do not.

Am I correct in thinking this? If so, does it matter which definition we adopt in practice?

Comment: You're misinterpreting here. A *point* of $\Bbb P^n$ *is* a *line* through the origin, hence is determined by its direction vector (which is defined up to nonzero scalar multiples). We are not talking about the points of the line, per se. Lines in projective space are something totally different: They correspond to $2$-planes through the origin in $\Bbb A^{n+1}$ and are $\Bbb P^1$'s embedded linearly in $\Bbb P^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I don't really understand what it is that I am misinterpreting. By a "line" in $\mathbb P^n$, I just meant an element of $\mathbb P^n$. All I mean in my post is that, according to definition (1), for all $x\in\mathbb P^n$ we have $0\in x$, whereas in definition (2), for all $x\in\mathbb P^n$ we have $0\not\in x$. (Here, $0$ denotes the point $(0,\dots,0)$ in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Ah, sorry, I see that my usage of "line" was non-standard. But still, do you agree that (1) and (2) are inequivalent?

Comment: You make a pedantic point that no one cares about. A line without the origin still identifies the line. One identifies subspaces through the origin by their bases (up to equivalence). Your picky point is magnified when I talk about the Grassmannian of $k$-planes; I certainly want to talk about the whole $k$-plane, even though I'm going to identify a point in the Grassmannian as an equivalence class of bases.

Answer (score 1):

The identification from definition $2$ to definition $1$ sends $x\in (\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\})/\sim$ to the vector space $\langle{x}\rangle\subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ it generates; the identification in the other direction sends a $1$-dimensional subspace $V\subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ to a basis element of it, which is well-defined modulo $\sim$. (It may be more intuitive over a field like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, where you can also require $|x| = 1$.) The asymmetry comes from the fact that $0$ does not generate the line it's on. But that's fine: we're treating $\mathbb{P}^n$ as an abstract space of its own, not trying to embed it in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$.